# EasyMock java: incompatible types: java.lang.ClassLoader cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends >

Tags: java, easymock

I am writing Testcases using Easymock for following code:

```
public class MyClass{
 public String getToken(String scope){
        String requestToken = "";
        try {
            URL keyStoreFile = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(keyStoreFileName);
            /*rest of the code*/
            }
}
```

I need to mock above line. It isrefering property file.
I have mocked as:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyClassTestCase {
@Test
public void testToken(){
MyClass myclass= new Myclass();

 PowerMock.createPartialMock(MyClass.class, "getClass");
        expect(myclass.getClass()).andReturn(classLoader);
        expect(classLoader.getResource(null)).andReturn(null);
        replay(classLoader,myclass);
}
}
```

Tried many ways, but not able to get through this. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your code doesn't compile at all and a lot of pieces are missing. Also, you are not giving the line where the compilation error occurs.

Finally, mocking that low is useless. I would just test with a `keystoreFileName` dedicated to test. And that's it.

Anyhow, I will guess. This line `expect(myclass.getClass()).andReturn(classLoader);` will give an error similar to your error. Because `getClass()` is returning a `Class<?>` (which is a `java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends>` in the compiler way to speak). But you are passing a `classloader` to `andReturn`. Which is not and will never be a `Class<?>`.

But I think you want to do the following:

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testToken(){
  Class<MyClass> clazz = PowerMock.createMock(Class.class);
  ClassLoader classLoader = PowerMock.createMock(ClassLoader.class);

  MyClass myclass = PowerMock.createPartialMock(MyClass.class, "getClass");
  EasyMock.expect((Class<MyClass>) myclass.getClass()).andReturn(clazz);
  expect(classLoader.getResource(null)).andReturn(null);

  replay(clazz, classLoader, myclass);

  myclass.getToken("scope");
}
```

So you basically just need to cast. And add a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. There are no cleaner way.

Then, it won't work anyway because the JVM won't let you mock a `Class`. Which will bring you back to my advice: Don't mock this.